# Should I use Android programming books before Android training?

Tags: android

Is it advisable to start first from android pdf books instead of the developers website because the developer.android.com Android training because they seem to go way too fast for me to comprehend and I have java knowledge

Comment: That all depends on your own capabilities. A book can help you a long way, but the only thing that can REALLY help you, is hands-on practice. Go ahead, play around a little and you'll see it'll work out after a while.

Comment: My question,Sire,is,You must have had exposure to the android tutorials onthe developer.android.com website and a few books,Would you reccommend I use the books before the website tutorials or the other way round

Comment: If you are asking for my personal preference, I like starting out with a small project, with an easy goal and just try to understand the logic. I only refer to the tutorials, if I actually get stuck...but that's just how I do things like that.

Comment: referring to tutorials isnt programming if u dont have a prior experience

Comment: But I believe, you stated, that you said, that you have 'Java knowledge', which counts as 'prior experience' in this case. But you're right, simply following a tutorial step by step without actually understanding what is done and why isn't programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone with a brief but ancient history with Java, reading O'Reilly's *Programming Android* cover to cover was great.  It gives you a very solid overview of app life cycles and quite a few other extremely important and useful components of Android including SQLite, intents, etc. (many of the basics, nicely distilled in one place).

Comment: Yes,I have started with this book but I found the Developer tutorials to be more comprehensive ...But This book is easier,Im guessing I should continue with the book so I wont burn out

Comment: The tutorials will walk you through step by step... the major benefit of the book (and many more broad overviews) is that you will get a theoretical background that will help you build apps that work with the system instead of against it; I probably should have emphasized the app lifecycle more, as that's extremely important and covered well.

* Which is not to say you shouldn't use BOTH, as both will help with different things.

Comment: I like this So till date,You have had no cause to go back to he developer.android.com website....

Comment: I don't mean to say the Android dev site isn't good; on the contrary, I use their doc often, and the tutorials are certainly useful for the specific topics they cover.  I just consider this a good all-in-one resource for your first round of "what's the process I'm going to be dealing with every time I start an app, and what are the common issues and paradigms I'll want/need to know?"

Answer (score 3):

I highly highly recommend this series: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE08A97D36D5A255F

The series will honestly teach you everything you need to know, and it's taught by a very knowledgeable person. Don't skip the first videos, they go by slowly, but help you comprehend the Android system.

If you have eclipse and do the android developer website tutorials. It should suffice. I don't think a book is necessary especially if you have knowledge of Java.

**1.** Watch the videos. **2.** Go through the tutorials. **3.** Get your fingers on the keyboard.

Those three steps in about a month period helped me release an app, and I had very little knowledge of Java.

Comment: Thats like 10GB,almost $100 worth of downloads here,In a 3rd world country,I will take the risk when I have the money on just one basis,So till date,You have had no cause to use the developer.android website and you are faring well

Comment: Well, even if those videos cost me $500, they are worth every penny. It's like paying for a class.

Comment: Hold on,Its still Marakana ORielly I have that,Thank you so much evwryone,God bless

Comment: Yes, it's Marakana. He had an old playlist of Android Bootcamp, and of course his 2012 is much better.

Answer (score 1):

This is best book

[Commonsware book](https://wares.commonsware.com#comsbook0802)

By Mark Murphy , you will also get a timely hour chat with Mark to solve your queries. This book also gets updated quickly so you won't be having an outdated version. By far best money spend on any book.